# One process keeps on running (out of four) while uploading S3 file using multi part upload and Multiprocessing(pool_async) in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing (pool_async) to upload multiple parts of a file to S3, using S3 multipart upload functionality. Below are the steps:

1. Generating multi part upload id (mpu_id).
2. Dividing the 2 gb file into chunks of 512 mb and uploading all of them in parallel using multiprocessing.
3. Completing the multipart upload.

While performing the second step. As the number of processor is 4, most of the time 3 processes are getting completed quickly(1-2 minutes), but one of them is taking more time to complete about 10 - 15 minutes.

Below is the sample code:

```
############################################################################################################################
## _upload function is being called to upload different parts of file parallely to s3 using apply_async of Multiprocessing##
############################################################################################################################
def _upload(local_path, bucket, key, file_size, mpu_id, part_num, offset, bytes):

    with FileChunkIO(local_path, 'rb', offset=offset,bytes=bytes) as data:
        print(offset,bytes,data)       
        part = client.upload_part(
            Body=data, Bucket=bucket, Key=key, UploadId=mpu_id, PartNumber=part_num)
        logger.info("{0} of {1} uploaded ({2:.3f}%) successfully - Part number : {3} ETag: {4} Status code : {5}".format(
            offset + bytes, file_size,
            as_percent(offset + bytes, file_size),part_num,part['ETag'],part["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"]))
        if part["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] != success_status:
            logging.warning(f"Part upload failed for below:\
            \nPartNumber  : {part_num}\
            \nETag        : {part['ETag']}\
            \nUploadId    : {mpu_id}\
            \nBucket      : {bucket}\
            \nkey         : {key}") 
    return part,part_num

## Callback function to get the result of the multiprcoessing function _upload.
parts = []
def mycallback(x):
    parts.append({"PartNumber": x[1], "ETag": x[0]['ETag']})

class S3MultipartUpload(FileUploads):

    def __init__(self,
                 path,
                 bucket,
                 part_size=file_part_size,
                 profile_name=None,
                 region_name=region,
                 verbose=False):
      self.total_bytes = os.stat(path).st_size
      self.part_bytes = part_size
      FileUploads.__init__(self,path,bucket)

    ## Create function generates mpu id for further processing.
    def create(self):
        logger.info("Executing create function to generate Multi part upload id.")
        try:
            mpu = client.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=self.bucket, Key=self.key)
            mpu_id = mpu["UploadId"]
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("An error occurred while creating the multipart upload id.", trace=True)
            Errors(e, logger=logger).errorrun()
        logger.info(f"Multipart upload id generated for key {self.key} in bucket {self.bucket} : {mpu_id} ")
        return mpu_id

    ## Upload function divide the file into parts and assign ETag to each part and upload it to S3.
    def upload(self, mpu_id, local_path, file_size,bucket,key):
        logger.info(f"Executing upload function to divide the file into chunks of {self.part_bytes/one_mb_bytes} MB and then uploading it to S3.")
        try:
            logger.info(f"Size of the file : {file_size/one_mb_bytes} MB")
            bytes_per_chunk = file_part_size
            logger.info(f"Size of each part after dividing the file : {bytes_per_chunk/one_mb_bytes} MB")
            chunk_amount = int(math.ceil(file_size / float(bytes_per_chunk)))
            logger.info(f"Number of parts created after dividing the file : {chunk_amount}")
            pool = Pool(processes=None)
            part_num = 1
            results = list()
            logger.info("Parallel execution started for uploading file parts to S3.")
            for i in range(chunk_amount):
                offset = i * bytes_per_chunk
                remaining_bytes = file_size - offset
                bytes = min([bytes_per_chunk, remaining_bytes])
                part_num = i + 1
                r = pool.apply_async(_upload,[local_path,bucket,key,file_size,mpu_id,part_num,offset,bytes],callback=mycallback)
                #print(r.get())
                part_num += 1
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            logger.info("Parallel execution completed and pool is closed.")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("An error occurred while uploading parts to S3.", trace=True)
            Errors(e, logger=logger).errorrun()
        logger.info("Upload process got completed.")
        return parts

    ## Complete function merges all the part or chunk into one file in S3 using mpu_id and ETag.
    def complete(self, mpu_id, parts):
        logger.info("Executing Multipart upload completion function to combine all the parts into one in S3.")
        try:
            parts_sorted = sorted(parts, key = lambda i: (i['PartNumber'], i['ETag']))
            result = client.complete_multipart_upload(
                Bucket=self.bucket,
                Key=self.key,
                UploadId=mpu_id,
                MultipartUpload={"Parts": parts_sorted})
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("An error occurred while uploading parts to S3.", trace=True)
            Errors(e, logger=logger).errorrun()
        logger.info(f"Checking status code for after completion of multipart upload : {result['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']}")
        return result

    def multi_part_upload(self, local_path,file_size):
        mpu_id = self.create() 
        parts  = self.upload(mpu_id,local_path,file_size,self.bucket,self.key)
        result = self.complete(mpu_id, parts)
        status_code = result["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"]
        if status_code == success_status:
            logger.info("Multipart upload was closed and completed successfully.")
        else:
            logger.warning("Multipart upload was not completed successfully.")
        return status_code
```

[Here's a screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oglW.png)

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just use boto3's `upload_file`, or `TransferConfig` if the default chunksize really isn't good enough?  Also, please don't include a screenshot of text, but the text itself.

Comment: @AnonCoward I was not aware of TransferConfig. I used it and now it is working fine.